# Exclude Category when showing product collection

Tags: collection, magento-1, product-collection, category-products, reports

I am showing Most popular products and I want to be able to exclude certain products from showing.

I thought the best way would be to exclude a category and when I want to exclude a product I can put it it the exclude category.

I need this to work even if the product is in a different category.

I am showing Most popular products with this:

```
$storeId2 = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $products2 = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
        ->setStoreId($storeId2)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId2)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc'); 

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products2);         
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products2);

$x = 1;
    foreach($products2 as $prod2){
        $inventory2 = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($prod2);
        $actual_stock3 = (int)$inventory2->getQty();

    if ($actual_stock3<1){
    echo $prod2->getName() . ' - ' . $actual_stock3 . ' - ' . number_format($prod2->getData('ordered_qty'), 0) . '</br>';   
    if ($x++ == 10) break;  
    }
    }
```

How do I exclude all products in, lets say category 151 even if the product is in another category?

Comment: Instead of putting a product in a category in order to be excluded from the most popular, why not add a new product attribute called 'exclude_from_most_popular'. then you can filter by that.

Comment: Ah yes, seems simple now. Let me try it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can left join the catalog_category_product table to match products in your "exclude category", then filter your collection to only return products with *no matches* in the joined table:

This should work, given the "exclude" category as `$excludeId`:

```
$products2->joinTable(
    ['exclude_category' => 'catalog/category_product'],
    'product_id=entity_id',
    ['category_id'],
    ['category_id' => $excludeId],
    'left'
);
$products2->getSelect()->where(new Zend_Db_Expr('exclude_category.category_id IS NULL'));
```

#### Update

I see, you are already joining the category index with `addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection()`  which results in a duplicate column "category_id". I updated the code to use an alias for the joined table, `exclude_category`.

Comment: Can you show this in my code please, cant get it to work. I'm obviously doing it wrong :)

Comment: @MikeTimTurner See update. Add the code before `$x=1`

Comment: btw, I tried it out and had to remove the `addAttributeToSelect` lines because in my case these attributes were not available in the reports collection. But YMMV

Comment: I didn't have to remove this, It worked great. thank you :)